# Spring WebFLow Handling Request in JSP

Tags: spring, spring-webflow-2

I am newbie to `Spring Webflow`, I have am using Custom `FlowHandler`

I can reach the respective Controller, but if set an attribute in a request Object I don't get it in JSP that is `View state`.

How can I proceed in this?

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't set anything to your request attributes in spring webflow - there is no need, besides webflow does some internal request redirecting and probably your attributes are los.

all the variables you create in the flow are available in view as if they were set by adding attribute to request. wether you create them via  tag or create by executing some service calls via  tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<on-start>      
   <evaluate expression="XXXControllerwsf.firstHit(flowRequestContext)" result="flowScope.res"/>
</on-start>
<decision-state id="urlcheck">
    <if test="flowScope.res.reurl== 'splash' " then="splash" else="change"/>
</decision-state>   
<view-state id="change" view="${flowScope.res.reurl}">       
</view-state>

<view-state id="splash" view="forward:/XXX/jsp1/XXXchange1.jsp">
    <transition on="buy" to="SignInSignUp"/>
</view-state>
</flow>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey Miceuz  thanks for Replying .....

```
<on-start>      
    <evaluate expression="XXXXControllerwsf.firstHit(flowRequestContext)" result="flowScope.res"/>
</on-start>
<decision-state id="urlcheck">
    <if test="flowScope.res.reurl== 'splash' " then="splash" else="change"/>
</decision-state>   
<view-state id="change" view="${flowScope.res.reurl}">       
</view-state>
<view-state id="splash" view="forward:/Jahia/jsp1/XXXXchange1.jsp">
   <transition on="buy" to="SignInSignUp"/>
</view-state>
</flow>
```

On start of the flow I am invoking a Contorller which extends FormAction

In firsthit Method I am setting a request Attribute as below

```
request.setAttribute("rajan", "rajanweww");
request.setAttribute("rajan", Object);
```

If i try to access in JSP , getting it as null... as you said Webflow has internal redirect.. Then how can I access the Value that has been set in Controller?